# Behavior of tests when run in xUnit 2

Tags: c#, .net, xunit2

From what I have read from the docs of xUnit, I could infer that by default any class is a test collection and runs in parallel. So my question is whether multiple appdomains are created for running these tests in parallel or is it one appdomain per assembly ? Could someone throw some light on how xunit does this.

Comment: Why not simply check xUnit configuration page, https://xunit.github.io/docs/configuring-with-json.html You can configure AppDomain behavior freely.

Comment: I don't think the xUnit configuration page answers that question.  It doesn't say how the app domains are used, just when.